# Query in form of webpage

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dynamic-queries

I have an SQL database which have about 10 columns and more than 5000 rows and i want to create a webpage where the user can deal with the database ( Sorting columns , filter results , add check mark (which represents ok value in the column).
What programs can i use ?

Comment: There are **many** options available, honestly. Usually depends on data involved and existing setup if any, and your knowledge. Generally though you'd use a backend language (like PHP using PDO queries, or something) and some HTML. What kind of programming have you done before?

Comment: Step 1.  Figure out who is going to host your site.  Step 2  - see what programming languages they support.

Comment: i used c# , php , sql . html before